# Sencha touch 2 - Can't nest a list inside of a panel or TabPanel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to show a list inside of a tab in TabPanel. When I just show the list - it works fine, but when I put it inside of a TabPanel it is not shown.

It is shown when I use this code in the launch event:

```
Ext.create('Ext.List', {
           fullscreen: true,
           itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{ID} <strong>{Name}</strong></div>',
           store: cityStore
        });
```

And when I use this code, it won't show (though the tabs are shown as need). I've also tried including the Ext.create list inside the items, still same result.

```
       Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel',{
            fullscreen: true,
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
            scrollable: true,
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Home',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    html: ['Welcome to my Pizza!'].join(""),
                    style: 'text-align: center;'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Search',
                    iconCls: 'search',
                    items: [
                          Ext.create('Ext.List', {
                              fullscreen: true,
                              itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{ID} <strong>{Name}</strong></div>',
                              store: cityStore
                          })
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    title: 'Pizza',
                    dock: 'top'
                }
            ]
        }).setActiveItem(1); // this is set for debugging only
```

What could be wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem Solved on Sencha forums:

You are nesting the list within a panel. Try to unnest it:

Code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel',{
    fullscreen: true,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    scrollable: true,
    items: [
        {
            title: 'Home',
            iconCls: 'home',
            html: ['Welcome to my Pizza!'].join(""),
            style: 'text-align: center;'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            title: 'Search',
            iconCls: 'search',
            store: cityStore,
            itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{ID} <strong>{Name}</strong></div>'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: 'Pizza',
            dock: 'top'
        }
    ]
}).setActiveItem(1);
```

Comment: Can you please explain 'unlist' it?  I am trying to accomplish this as well.

Comment: You have to put the list as if it were a tab itself.